# Flash CS6 Action Script 2 hitTest not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, hittest

My Action Script 2 hitTest isn't working. I've tried searching for the answer, but found nothing.
The hitTest isn't responding with the gotoAndStop I've assigned to it. 
Here is my code:

```
walkspeed = 25;
jumping = false;
scottjab = false;
crouching = false;
scottslash = false;



scott.onEnterFrame = function(){
if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this.gotoAndStop("scottCrouch");
    crouching = true;
} else if(Key.isDown(78) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this.gotoAndStop("scottJab");
    scottjab = true;
} else if(Key.isDown(77) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this.gotoAndStop("scottSlash");
    scottslash = true;
} else if(Key.isDown(Key.UP) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this.gotoAndStop("scottJump");
    jumping = true;
} else if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this._x -= walkspeed;
    this.gotoAndStop("scottWalk");
} else if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this._x += walkspeed;
    this.gotoAndStop("scottWalk");
} else if(!jumping && !scottjab && !crouching){
    this.gotoAndStop("scottIdle");
}
} 

ilsa.onEnterFrame = function(){
if(scott.scottJab.pad.hitTest(this)){
    this.gotoAndStop("ilsa Hit");
} else {
    this.gotoAndStop("ilsa Idle");
}
}
```

The two characters ('scott' and 'ilsa') are also on different layers, if that helps. And there are 4 total scenes in the file.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you try to write `trace("hitTest");` after `this.gotoAndStop("ilsa Hit");` in your ilsa.onEnterFrame function, what is the result (output)?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen. What should I do?

Comment: And if you try: `trace(scott); trace(scott.scottJab); trace(scott.scottJab.pad);` what happens?

Comment: Again, nothing happens.

Comment: That's normal. You have to put these instructions `outside` of your `ilsa.onEnterFrame function`. What is the output?

Comment: @helloflash The output is: _level0.scott
undefined
undefined

Comment: `trace(scott.scottJab);` returns `undefined`. That's the reason why your hitTest doesn't work. The compiler can't find `scott.scottJab.pad` because there's a problem with `scott.scottJab`. Do your verifications here.

Comment: The `undefined` output for `trace(scott.scottJab);` isn't normal. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from your if statement:

```
if (scott.scottJab.pad.hitTest(this)) {/* ... */}
```

The object you are targeting `doesn't exist`, `isn't named` or isn't `correctly named`. Is there an object named `pad` contained in an object named `scottJab` itself contained in the object named `scott`?

Comment: Yes, there is, in fact.

Comment: @Scott - Is scottJab named with "J" uppercase? - If you write trace("enterFrame"); at the beginning of your ilsa.onEnterFrame function, does it play? - Is ilsa correctly named?

Comment: "ilsa" is correctly named, because everything plays after that function, EXCEPT for the scott.scottJab. And it is named with an uppercase J. @helloflash